# Unreal Engine calls these macros...is this normal in C++ now?

Tags: c++

I used to be a C++ programmer and to me a macro was a preprocessor definition using`#define`.

Now I am getting back into programming with Unreal engine which uses C++ but there are all these *macros* `UCLASS()` `UFUNCTION()` `FORCELINE` that the UNreal tutorial calls a macro. I've never seen anything like this before and would like to understand it.

I am not asking what the macro does in Unreal, but for someone to help me fill in my knowledge gap with C++ so I (as a developer) can understand how to design and when to implement ***this type*** of macro. Even giving me a link to a guide or something is fine. I tried searching using terms *macro, C++, UCLass, Unreal* but those terms aren't really coming up with a C++ definition of *this* macro.

```
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "Pickup.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class BATTERYCOLLECTOR_API APickup : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public: 
    // Sets default values for this actor's properties
    APickup();

    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;
```

Comment: What's your question exactly? Why do you think those macros are different from what you know about macros? Why do you think they're not defined with `#define`?

Comment: Have you searched the engine code for the macros and looked to see how they are defined?

Comment: Those definitely look like macros to me. They don't fit anything *else* in the language syntax.

Comment: MACRO are for text substitution, it is not only flag for `#ifndef`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The Unreal Engine C++ codebase uses a custom preprocessor, called [*Unreal Header Tool (UHT)*](https://www.unrealengine.com/blog/unreal-property-system-reflection) to generate custom Runtime Type Information (RTTI) from your C++ code. It manages to do so by looking for these special macro-like annotations in the code. So pedantically speaking, they are not simple C++ macros, there's more to them than that.

I'm not a user of Unreal Engine, so I'm not aware of the implementation details. I don't know if the UHT preprocessor strips them out after running, or maybe they are just defined to nothing for the C++ compiler, e.g.:

```
#if !RUNNING_UHT
    #define UCLASS()
#endif
```

Both approaches seem valid.

> Is this normal C++?

It depends. It's certainly not *Standard* C++. Macros are less used in C++ because the language provides better options in most cases (e.g.: inline functions, enums, `const`, templates), so you probably won't see that kind of macro usage in most codebases.

Comment: Thanks I accept your answer because you specifically answered the questions I framed and I can look up UHT to learn more. For anyone else coming to this answer, the answer by @mykola is really good too. It really helps fill in my knowledge gap about the use of macros and how UHT, UBT is implemented.

Comment: Note that macros actually *are* used pretty often in the wild, despite the existence of those other language features. Also, note that this sounds very similar to what the Qt `moc` tool does--but note that the Qt macros really are used as macros, i.e., they are eventually passed to the C++ preprocessor rather than being removed by the `moc` tool.

Answer (score 11):

As the Unreal Engine documentation says:

*The class declaration defines the name of the class, what class it inherits from and, thus, any functions and variables it inherits, and other engine and editor specific behavior that may be desired via class specifiers and metadata. The syntax for declaring a class is as follows:*

```
UCLASS([specifier, specifier, ...], [meta(key=value, key=value, ...)])
class ClassName : ParentName
{
    GENERATED_UCLASS_BODY()
}
```

*The declaration consists of a standard C++ class declaration for the class. Above the standard declaration, descriptors such as class specifiers and metadata are passed to the UCLASS macro. These are used to create the UClass for the class being declared, which can be thought of as the engine's specialized representation of the class. Also, the `GENERATED_UCLASS_BODY()` macro must be placed at the very beginning of the class body.*

This macro is created to add some metadata features to engine classes like RTTI, Reflection e.t.c... **This macro is not standard macro provided by C++ STD library, but the macro written by Epic Games to fit Unreal Engine needs.**

The more information about Unreal Engine [Gameplay Classes](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/UnrealArchitecture/Reference/Classes/index.html) and the macro they used.

Here is the example of some macro code denerated by Unreal Engine for simple game class:

```
// Copyright 1998-2015 Epic Games, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
/*===========================================================================
    C++ class header boilerplate exported from UnrealHeaderTool.
    This is automatically generated by the tools.
    DO NOT modify this manually! Edit the corresponding .h files instead!
===========================================================================*/

#include "ObjectBase.h"

#ifdef MYPROJECTCODE_MyProjectCodeGameMode_generated_h
#error "MyProjectCodeGameMode.generated.h already included, missing '#pragma once' in MyProjectCodeGameMode.h"
#endif
#define MYPROJECTCODE_MyProjectCodeGameMode_generated_h

#define AMyProjectCodeGameMode_EVENTPARMS
#define AMyProjectCodeGameMode_RPC_WRAPPERS
#define AMyProjectCodeGameMode_RPC_WRAPPERS_NO_PURE_DECLS \
    static inline void StaticChecks_Implementation_Validate() \
    { \
    }


#define AMyProjectCodeGameMode_CALLBACK_WRAPPERS
#define AMyProjectCodeGameMode_INCLASS_NO_PURE_DECLS \
    private: \
    static void StaticRegisterNativesAMyProjectCodeGameMode(); \
    friend MYPROJECTCODE_API class UClass* Z_Construct_UClass_AMyProjectCodeGameMode(); \
    public: \
    DECLARE_CLASS(AMyProjectCodeGameMode, AGameMode, COMPILED_IN_FLAGS(0 | CLASS_Transient | CLASS_Config), 0, MyProjectCode, MYPROJECTCODE_API) \
    DECLARE_SERIALIZER(AMyProjectCodeGameMode) \
    /** Indicates whether the class is compiled into the engine */    enum {IsIntrinsic=COMPILED_IN_INTRINSIC}; \
    UObject* _getUObject() const { return const_cast<AMyProjectCodeGameMode*>(this); }


#define AMyProjectCodeGameMode_INCLASS \
    private: \
    static void StaticRegisterNativesAMyProjectCodeGameMode(); \
    friend MYPROJECTCODE_API class UClass* Z_Construct_UClass_AMyProjectCodeGameMode(); \
    public: \
    DECLARE_CLASS(AMyProjectCodeGameMode, AGameMode, COMPILED_IN_FLAGS(0 | CLASS_Transient | CLASS_Config), 0, MyProjectCode, MYPROJECTCODE_API) \
    DECLARE_SERIALIZER(AMyProjectCodeGameMode) \
    /** Indicates whether the class is compiled into the engine */    enum {IsIntrinsic=COMPILED_IN_INTRINSIC}; \
    UObject* _getUObject() const { return const_cast<AMyProjectCodeGameMode*>(this); }


#define AMyProjectCodeGameMode_STANDARD_CONSTRUCTORS \
    /** Standard constructor, called after all reflected properties have been initialized */ \
    MYPROJECTCODE_API AMyProjectCodeGameMode(const FObjectInitializer& ObjectInitializer); \
    DEFINE_DEFAULT_OBJECT_INITIALIZER_CONSTRUCTOR_CALL(AMyProjectCodeGameMode) \
private: \
    /** Private copy-constructor, should never be used */ \
    MYPROJECTCODE_API AMyProjectCodeGameMode(const AMyProjectCodeGameMode& InCopy); \
public:


#define AMyProjectCodeGameMode_ENHANCED_CONSTRUCTORS \
private: \
    /** Private copy-constructor, should never be used */ \
    MYPROJECTCODE_API AMyProjectCodeGameMode(const AMyProjectCodeGameMode& InCopy); \
public: \
    DEFINE_DEFAULT_OBJECT_INITIALIZER_CONSTRUCTOR_CALL(AMyProjectCodeGameMode)


#undef UCLASS_CURRENT_FILE_NAME
#define UCLASS_CURRENT_FILE_NAME AMyProjectCodeGameMode


#undef UCLASS
#undef UINTERFACE
#if UE_BUILD_DOCS
#define UCLASS(...)
#else
#define UCLASS(...) \
AMyProjectCodeGameMode_EVENTPARMS
#endif


#undef GENERATED_UCLASS_BODY
#undef GENERATED_BODY
#undef GENERATED_IINTERFACE_BODY
#define GENERATED_UCLASS_BODY() \
PRAGMA_DISABLE_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS \
public: \
    AMyProjectCodeGameMode_RPC_WRAPPERS \
    AMyProjectCodeGameMode_CALLBACK_WRAPPERS \
    AMyProjectCodeGameMode_INCLASS \
    AMyProjectCodeGameMode_STANDARD_CONSTRUCTORS \
public: \
PRAGMA_POP


#define GENERATED_BODY() \
PRAGMA_DISABLE_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS \
public: \
    AMyProjectCodeGameMode_RPC_WRAPPERS_NO_PURE_DECLS \
    AMyProjectCodeGameMode_CALLBACK_WRAPPERS \
    AMyProjectCodeGameMode_INCLASS_NO_PURE_DECLS \
    AMyProjectCodeGameMode_ENHANCED_CONSTRUCTORS \
private: \
PRAGMA_POP
```

And the class for it.

```
// Copyright 1998-2015 Epic Games, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
#pragma once
#include "GameFramework/GameMode.h"
#include "MyProjectCodeGameMode.generated.h"

    UCLASS(minimalapi)
    class AMyProjectCodeGameMode : public AGameMode
    {
        GENERATED_BODY()

    public:
        AMyProjectCodeGameMode(const FObjectInitializer& ObjectInitializer);
    };
```

As you can see this macro adds to classes extra field variables and methods to provide interface for Unreal Engine metadata info. So the engine can use this info to build levels, spawn players e.t.c...

The macro defined by engine cannot be rewritten, exept you want to design your own engine framework to add some new features (with new macro defenitions), or modify current Unreal Engine to fit your specific needs (wich is a realy hard work).

Comment: Ehm the standard says nothing about Unreal macros.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: Thank you I overlooked this.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful!  I forgot lots about C++ and macros but you explained it in a way that refreshed my memory and explained how and why the Unreal Engine is doing what it is with macros too.